# External & local CSS is not considered when rendering page to PDF using PhantomJS

Tags: css, angularjs, node.js, phantomjs, stylesheet

Is there a way to force PhantomJS to read CSS styles?

I'm currently using Angular and UI-Grid to generate a table and when a value in the table meets a condition (e.g. *if value > 1000*) it will get assigned to a specific CSS class. Then I generate a PDF file using PhantomJS.

***CSS***

```
.data-records-alarm {
    color: red !important;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I have noticed that it recognizes "*text-align: center;*" property but it won't recognize the color "**color: red !important;**".

I have also tried "color: red;" or moving the CSS style and having it locally in my HTML file but it doesn't work.

Im currently using PhantomJS 2.0.0 and tested the Chrome & Firefox browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only way i got it to work is by using `-webkit-text-fill-color` instead of `color`

```
.data-records-alarm {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: red !important;
    text-align: center;}
```